# PHPSpreadSheet: Combining csv files into one sheet

Tags: csv, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I'm using PHPSpreadSheet to create csv files. What I need to do is combine several csv files into one. For example:

FILE A:

ROW 1: one, two, three

FILE B:

ROW 1: four, fix, six

What I'd like to generate is:

COMBINED FILE:

ROW 1: one, two, three
ROW 2: four, five, six

I've reviewed the PHPSpreadSheet documentation but haven't found anything. I've found tools that would add additional csv files as new worksheets into the spreadsheet, but we need to have a single large csv file.